How do i create a child process of "ibus-ui-gtk3?"
Problem statement:  Each time I reboot, I get a notification:

Please unset QT_IM_MODULE and GTK_IM_MODULE environment variables
and 'ibus-daemon --panel disable' should be executed as a child process
of ibus-ui-gtk3 component.

I'm running Ubuntu-Studio 24.04.  In fact, I just upgraded from Ubuntu-Studio 23.10.  I had this problem before I updated from 23.10.
I may be able to simply unset the 2 indicated environment variables (in my .bashrc)?
But, I have no idea about "creating a child process of ibus-ui-gtk3.  How can I do this?
How do i create a child process of "ibus-ui-gtk3."
UPDATE1
My removing ibus-daemon from the autostart failed to change behavior.
UPDATE2
Setting both of the specified environment variables to "" also failed to change behavior.

I have a Kubuntu and I have same problem
